# Extract database schema in correct order for insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating an application which is migrating database from old to new. My database has created in **SQL Server 2005.** There are more than 125 tables in the database and every tables are related to it's parent tables.
My problem is i want to get a **list of tables** available in my database. but it should be **sorted accordingly their relationship.** for example there are three tables

```
Country
City
Customer
```

The **countryid** will be inserted in **City** table from **Country** table and the **cityid** will be inserted into **Customer** table from **City** table.

So, How to get the list of tables which is sorted by their relationship.
parent table should be come first then their child tables so, when i transfer the data from old to new the application should not give **FOREIGN KEY CONTRAIN** error.

Comment: I updated your title to better reflect what you are looking for.

Comment: Why don't go for a script like below wherein on your destination database you can drop FK -- migrate data -- re-create all the foreign key constraints:http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1376/disable-enable-drop-and-recreate-sql-server-foreign-keys/

Comment: @Deepshikha My database is very complexed. I am not permitted to drop and recreate the foreign keys. Because, there are some other properties are set in fk also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the reverse-engineering tools such as [DB designer fork](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdesigner-fork/), [MYSQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) or  MS SQL Server Management Studio? The latter should allow you to right click **Database Diagrams -> New Database Diagram** to generate the schema.

Or are you not looking for a visual representation but a textual list?

Comment: No, I don't want to get diagram or design. I have already created it in SSMO. I just wanted a simple list. So, i can execute my queries in order of that list.